# How can I update mongodb document for adding a new item to array?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I couldn't figure out insert to a sub array...

- _id
- MyArray
- --Item
- ----ArrayItemId
- ----Name

I want to insert items to MyArray...

How my update document should be?

```
MyCollection.Update( 
 new QueryDocument { { "_id", MyObject.Id } },
 new UpdateDocument { { "$set", new BsonDocument { { "MyArray", 
       new BsonArray { new BsonDocument {{ "ArrayItemId", myArrayField.Id }},
                       new BsonDocument {{ "Name", myArrayField.Name }} }}}}}, 
 UpdateFlags.None);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inserting in an array is done using the [`$push`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) operator.

As a side note, you don't need to use `QueryDocument` and `UpdateDocument`. There's a much easier helper syntax:

```
MyCollection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", MyObject.Id), 
                    Update.PushWrapped("MyArray", myArrayField)
```

Note that `PushWrapped<T>` allows to push documents, while `Push` accepts only such types that can be represented by a simple field in MongoDB.

Comment: thanks. But for Update.PushWrapped what should I reference... Intellicense is not seeing it...

Comment: I think it is now ... new UpdateBuilder().PushWrapped in the new version

Answer (score 31):

Syntax for new MongoDB c# async adapter:

```
var filter = Builders<myObject>
             .Filter.Eq(e => e.Name, "name");

var update = Builders<myObject>.Update
        .Push<String>(e => e.MyArray, myArrayField);

await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: what should i write behalf of string

Comment: you can skip the "String" in Push<String> as it can be inferred from the specified datatype in update field (e.MyArray)